# How creating a non root user by simply setting up a random UID in a container FROM scratch works?

Tags: docker, go, dockerfile

I'm setting up a Golang server with Docker and I want an unprivileged user to launch it inside its container for safety.

Here is the simple Dockerfile I use. I import my binary in the container and set a random UID.

```
FROM scratch
WORKDIR /app
COPY --chown=1001:1001 my-app-binary my-app-binary
USER 1001
CMD ["/app/my-app-binary"]
```

If my server listens to port 443, It doesn't work since it requires privileged rights. So my app is running by an unprivileged user as intended.

Nonetheless User 1001 was not properly created. The tutorials I saw tell me to create the user in an intermediate 'builder' container (alpine for instance) and import /etc/passwd from it. I didn't find any example doing what I do. ([here](https://medium.com/@chemidy/create-the-smallest-and-secured-golang-docker-image-based-on-scratch-4752223b7324) one tutorial I followed)

Can someone explains to me why my solution works or what I didn't understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**DISCLOSURE: In my answer I've used quotes from [this blog post](https://medium.com/redbubble/running-a-docker-container-as-a-non-root-user-7d2e00f8ee15). I'm neither the author of this post nor in any way related to the author.**

It's expected - containers can run under a user that is not known to the container. Quoting [`docker run` docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#user):

> `root` (id = 0) is the default user within a container. The image developer can create additional users. Those users are accessible by name. **When passing a numeric ID, the user does not have to exist in the container.**
>
> -- https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/#user

It helps you resolve issues like this:

> Sometimes, when we run builds in Docker containers, the build creates files in a folder that’s mounted into the container from the host (e.g. the source code directory). This can cause us pain, because those files will be owned by the `root` user. When an ordinary user tries to clean those files up when preparing for the next build (for example by using `git clean`), they get an error and our build fails.
>
> -- https://medium.com/redbubble/running-a-docker-container-as-a-non-root-user-7d2e00f8ee15#7d3a

And it's possible because:

> Fortunately, `docker run` gives us a way to do this: [the --user parameter](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#user). We're going to use it to specify the user ID (UID) and group ID (GID) that Docker should use. This works because Docker containers all share the same kernel, and therefore the same list of UIDs and GIDs, even if the associated usernames are not known to the containers (more on that later).
>
> -- https://medium.com/redbubble/running-a-docker-container-as-a-non-root-user-7d2e00f8ee15#b430

The above applies to [USER dockerfile command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#user) as well.

Using a UID not known to the container has some gotchas:

> #### Your user will be $HOME-less
>
> What we’re actually doing here is asking our Docker container to do things using the ID of a user it knows nothing about, and that creates some complications. Namely, it means that the user is missing some of the things we’ve learned to simply expect users to have — things like a home directory. This can be troublesome, because it means that all the things that live in $HOME — temporary files, application settings, package caches — now have nowhere to live. The containerised process just has no way to know where to put them.
>
> This can impact us when we’re trying to do user-specific things. We found that it caused problems using `gem install` (though using Bundler is OK), or running code that relies on `ENV['HOME']`. So it may mean that you need to make some adjustments if you do either of those things.
>
> #### Your user will be nameless, too
>
> It also turns out that we can’t easily share usernames between a Docker host and its containers. That’s why we can’t just use `docker run --user=$(whoami)` — the container doesn't know about your username. It can only find out about your user by its UID.
>
> That means that when you run `whoami` inside your container, you'll get a result like `I have no name!`. That's entertaining, but if your code relies on knowing your username, you might get some confusing results.
>
> -- https://medium.com/redbubble/running-a-docker-container-as-a-non-root-user-7d2e00f8ee15#e295

Comment: Great answer. Thank you. Also from the [doc](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add): "Using numeric IDs requires no lookup and will not depend on container root filesystem content."